# Ajax post form working 2 times then reloads page with a get URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am working on a login form that gets loaded inside a `div` (parent of `.messageboxcontent`) with `.load` on a button press. It all works till the 3rd time I press submit where the `div` disappears again (I guess by reload of the page and the `div` CSS is hidden). The URL has the `$_POST` data added after the 3rd submit (`?username=<whatever_I_Fill_In_As_3rd>`).

```
<div class="messageboxcontent">
<form id="ajaxform">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Gebruikersnaam: </td><td><input type="text" name="username"  /></td><td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Registreer" id="submit" />
</form>
</div>


<script>
$('form').on('submit', function( event )
{
var dataString = $(this).serialize();
event.stopPropagation();

//event.preventDefault();

$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "register.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('.messageboxcontent').html(response);//FIXED by changing .messageboxcontent to parent.
    }
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

I tried different kind of approaches like:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
//..
}

//

$('#ajaxform').submit(function(event) {
//..
}

//

$(document).ready(function() 
{    
$("#ajaxform").on("submit", function( event )
{
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    //event.stopPropagation();

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("div.messageboxcontent").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false; //with and without this.
});
});
```

Comment: I think i fixed it. Obviously i had to renew the .html with the parent of div.messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

Be consistent  with quotes. Also close your div (`<div class="messageboxcontent"></div>`)
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ajaxform").on("submit", function( event ){
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("div.messageboxcontent").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm closing that div just above my script. I tried having the script inside the div too without result. Your code does not work, i get the exact same result. I will add it to what i tried.

Comment: remove return false; see what happens.

Comment: Exactly the same happens.

Comment: Post your link here for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` inside your ajax function would stop the page from reloading.

Secondly, jQuery works with selector methods via class or id - so, in your case, you will want to use `$('#ajaxform')`.

Lastly, the possible reason why you are facing with unexpected result like after 3rd time is because your form is wrapped inside a div that you want to manipulate the result.  So, try rewrapping your DIV element to this: `<div class="messageboxcontent"></div>` and have your `<form>` stand on its own separately from messageboxcontent div.

Comment: use either `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` - not both otherwise it'll cancel each other out and allow page to reload.

Comment: Putting the form out of the div seems to help. But in the table within the form i have a 3th collumn that gets manipulated based on the return results. <td>Gebruikersnaam: </td><td><input type="text" name="username"  /></td><td><?php foreach ($userResult as $r) {echo "<h6>".$r." </h6>"; } ?></td>